# Cheerio/NodeJS get a div's background image

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I'm trying to get a `div`'s background image from a remote page. I use cheerio for DOM operations, but can't use `css()` function like jQuery.

Here is my code:

```
var $ = cheerio.load(body,{ decodeEntities: false });
console.log($(".image").css('background-image'));
```

I know that the cheerio is just a DOM operator, but is there any way to get that `background-image` from the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Cheerio site's home page; emphasis mine:

> Cheerio parses markup and provides an API for traversing/manipulating the resulting data structure. It does not interpret the result as a web browser does. **Specifically, it does not** produce a visual rendering, **apply CSS**, load external resources, or execute JavaScript. If your use case requires any of this functionality, you should consider projects like PhantomJS or JSDom.

Answer (score 0):

> Cheerio does not actually parse and apply CSS, the css method can only return styling that has been applied in-line via the style attribute. If you need to do more advanced CSS scraping, I would recommend using jsDom.

https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/357#issuecomment-31659300